# Как сделать показ слова по случайным буквам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

```
import time
import random

answer = 'test'

def func():
    current_hint = '*'*len(answer)
    new_hint = random.randrange(len(answer))
    new_answer = current_hint[:new_hint] + answer[new_hint] + current_hint[new_hint+1:]
    print(str(new_answer))

while True:
    func()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Вот, что делает этот код:

```
***t
**s*
***t 
t***
```

Мне нужно, чтобы то, что получилось, добавлялось к тем буквам которые уже были, ну вот так:

```
*e**
*es*
*est 
test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import time
import random


def func(text, need_symbol):
    len_text = len(text)

    if need_symbol >= len_text:
        return text

    indexs = []

    # Пока не наберем нужное количество индексов, из цикла не выйдем
    while len(indexs) < need_symbol:
        i = random.choice(range(len_text))

        # Если уже есть индекс
        if i in indexs:
            continue

        indexs.append(i)

    return ''.join(c if i in indexs else '*' for i, c in enumerate(text))


answer = 'test'


for i in range(len(answer)):
    new_answer = func(answer, i + 1)
    print(new_answer)

    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Очевидно надо сохранять подсказки. Для этого удобно будет воспользоваться словарем.

Попробуйте так:

```
answer = 'test'

hint = dict()

def func(answer, current_hint):
    seen_idx = set(current_hint.keys())
    idx = random.choice(list(set(range(len(answer))) - seen_idx))
    current_hint[idx] = answer[idx]
    return ''.join([x if i in current_hint else '*' for i,x in enumerate(answer)])
```

Тестирование:

```
In [186]: while True:
     ...:     print(func(answer, hint))
     ...:     time.sleep(3)
     ...:
     ...:
***t
*e*t
te*t
test
```

Comment: Можно упростить: `return ''.join([hint[i] if i in hint else '*' for i,x in enumerate(answer)])` -> `return ''.join(x if i in hint else '*' for i,x in enumerate(answer))`

Comment: @gil9red, Спасибо, так действительно элегантнее выглядит :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import time
from numpy import random 

def func(word):
    n = len(word)
    new_hint = random.permutation(len(answer))
    current_hint = '*'*len(answer)
    for i in range(n):
        j = new_hint[i]
        current_hint = current_hint[:j] + answer[j] + current_hint[j+1:]
        print(current_hint)
        time.sleep(3)

answer = 'test'        
func(answer)
```

Answer (score 2):

Если рассмотреть задачу с точки зрения ООП, то есть строка (слово), содержащая символы, каждый из которых имеет одно из двух возможных состояний (скрыт - не скрыт).

```
from time import sleep
from random import shuffle

class Char:
    '''Объект - символ, изначально скрыт'''
    def __init__(self, char):
        self.value = char
        self.hide = True
    def __repr__(self):
        return "*" if self.hide else self.value

class UnhideString:

    def __init__(self, string):
        # коллекция хранит объекты символы в неизменном порядке
        self._chars = tuple(map(Char, string))

        # а тут эти же символы будут перемешаны
        self.shuffle_chars = list(self._chars)
        shuffle(self.shuffle_chars)

    def print(self):
        while self.shuffle_chars:
            # забираем последний (после перемешивания) символ
            char = self.shuffle_chars.pop()
            # изменяем свойство
            char.hide = False
            # вывод строки в изначальном порядке
            print(*self._chars, sep='', end='')

            if self.shuffle_chars:
                print('\r', end='')
                sleep(1)
            else:
                print()

UnhideString("test").print()
```

Answer (score 2):

Кажется, все варианты уже предложили, включая через `shuffle`, но не пропадать же коду, да и `yield` ни у кого вроде нету:

```
import time
import random

answer = 'test'

def func():
    new_answer = ['*'] * len(answer)
    idx = list(range(len(answer)))
    random.shuffle(idx)
    for i in idx:
        new_answer[i] = answer[i]
        yield ''.join(new_answer)

for new_answer in func():
    print(f'\r{new_answer}', end='')
    time.sleep(3)
```

Мне кажется у меня наиболее понятный код. Просто перемешиваем индексы, потом берём их по очереди и ставим вместо '*' реальный символ по этому индексу. Хотя все ответы в чём-то похожи, конечно.